# TRIGGER BEFORE UPDATE doesn't work

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table composed by a PK of 3 fields; 2 fields are FK that refers each one to one table.

I want to let work the UPDATE only if the  new value of **IDsentiero** is equal than the old value.

**But i don't get any signal...**

```
CREATE TRIGGER BEFORE_UPDATE_ON_SENTIERO
BEFORE UPDATE ON SENTIERO
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF      (NEW.IDsentiero<>OLD.IDsentiero) THEN

                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'UPDATE: I sentieri devono mantenere lo stesso ID';

END IF;


END$$
```